# Can I use ContentType.objects.get in templatetags?

Tags: django, django-templates

I kept get this error while attempting to use contenttype in the templatetags.

> django.contrib.contenttypes.models.ContentType.DoesNotExist: ContentType matching query does not exist.

I am trying to get an object by passing the modelname and pk as string to the simple_tag.  Below is the codes. I have other custom filters in the same file that work fine.

```
# in templatetags\srrp_tags.py
from django import template
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def get_object(modelname, id):
    ctype = ContentType.objects.get(model=modelname) # this line trigger the error
    model = ctype.model_class()
    return model.objects.get(pk=id)
```

In my html, model and primary are both string value

```
# in templates\srrp\index.html
{% load srrp_tags %}
...

{% get_object modelname|title primary %}
```

I have use the exact same code for the Contenttype in the view.py and it retrieve the required model with no issue.

```
# in view.py
class srrpListView(LoginRequiredMixin, PermissionRequiredMixin, ListView):
...
    def get_queryset(self):
        modelname = self.kwargs.get('modelname')                
        ctype = ContentType.objects.get(model=modelname) # same code
        self.model = ctype.model_class()        
        return self.model.objects.select_related().values()
```

Any advice is much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Maybe add a `print(modelname)` to your `get_object()` function to see what the actual value is that causes the error?

Comment: i have added print(modelname), the modelname is correct, the exact same as the one in my view.py